# Python install packages

Tags: python, installation, package

How do i install packages, specificity  http://klappnase.bubble.org/TkinterTreectrl, do i drag the file somewhere or install using the terminal? also how do install from the terminal if thats what i need to do?

Comment: operating system is linux Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you've downloaded the zip file via your browser which put it in `${HOME}/Downloads`

Open a terminal and try the following commands:

```
cd ${HOME}/Downloads
ls # a bunch of stuff is here, one of the files should be TkinterTreectrl-1.0.zip 
unzip TkinterTreectrl-1.0.zip 
cd TkinterTreectrl-1.0
sudo python setup.py install
```

Of course, you might need to get a couple of the dependencies and install those too.

Installing python modules usually only takes `<sudo> python setup.py install` once you've unpacked the archive containing the files.

For future reference, here's how to unpack files with various extensions:

```
.zip    --> unzip filename.zip
.gz     --> gunzip filname.gz
.tar.gz --> tar -xzvf filename.tar.gz
.tgz    --> tar -xzvf filename.tgz
.bz2    --> bunzip2 filename.bz2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Ubuntu you should just use the Software Center.

```
sudo apt-get install {package-name}
```

Should be easy as that. Also yes, this should be from the terminal.

Comment: "Should be as easy as that" -- That depends on whether the package is popular enough to make it into the Ubuntu repos or not.

Comment: Well of course, but the Ubuntu repos are pretty massive, especially when it comes to python packages. Otherwise you could just download it and add it to your path.

Comment: I wasn't able to find this package in my repos -- Of course, I'm using a slightly older version of Ubuntu, but the OP didn't specify an Ubuntu version.